# Is it implicit in python that 'other' is another object in a list? Parameter has never been introduced properly

Tags: python, class, parameters

I just don't understand how an example in a book lists a parameter 'other' which is never introduced. When called the function, Python automatically understands it to be the other elements of the Class? 
See the example:

```
def get_neighbors(self, others, radius, angle):
    """Return the list of neighbors within the given radius and angle."""
    boids = []
    for other in others:
        if other is self: continue
        offset = other.pos - self.pos

        # if not in range, skip it
        if offset.mag > radius: 
            continue

        # if not within viewing angle, skip it
        if self.vel.diff_angle(offset) > angle:
            continue

        # otherwise add it to the list
        boids.append(other)

    return boids
```

Nowhere else in the code there is a mention of 'other'. 
Thanks, just trying to understand the mechanisms.

Comment: That is simply the syntax of loop construction. You're providing a name to apply to the value in each iteration, which allows you to refer to that value.

Comment: Are you talking about the parameter "other**s**" or the loop variable "other" (which is *not* a parameter)?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about 'others', not other. Of course, when you have 'others' you can loop for other in 'others'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated answer, in response to comment

Python doesn't have any special behavior for a method parameter named "others", or for any of the other parameters in your example.

Most likely the book you're reading simply didn't explain (yet) how that function will be invoked. It's also possible that the book made a mistake (in which case, perhaps you should find a better book!).

#### Original answer (for posterity)

The name `other` is declared by the `for` statement:

```
for other in others:
   ...
```

From [the Python documentation for the `for` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the iterator, in the order of ascending indices. Each item in turn is assigned to the target list using the standard rules for assignments, and then the suite is executed.

Here, "the iterator" is derived from the list `others`, and "the target list" is simply the variable `other`. So on each iteration through the loop, the `other` variable is assigned ("using the standard rules for assignments") the next value from the list.

Comment: Thank you. But I was talking about the initial 'others' as a parameter, not inside the loop (other)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. The full code is available at: http://greenteapress.com/complexity/Boids.py

Comment: @B_Furtado: It's not clear what you don't understand. Perhaps you just don't fully understand [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and Python's dynamic type system?

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I actually didn't know the concept of 'duck typing'. Like a said, I'm just a beginner in Python. Anyway, as mentioned in the comment below, I finally did understand. 'Others' in the case refers to the list of all 'Boid()', or 'all selfs' for my understanding. The way to apply 'others' in the real case is simply to include one conditional 'if other is self; continue'. Thanks for the help. Best,

Answer (score 0):

The DocString for that method should include the list of arguments and explain the expected type for each (I am planning to update this code soon, and I will improve the documentation).

In this case, others should be a list (or other sequence) of objects that have an attribute named pos (probably the same type as other).

Note that there is nothing special about the name 'others'.

Comment: I think I get it! It's the same list of created Boids(). When it goes through the list, if it is self it disregards the element and goes to the next on the list. Thus, there is no need to have a list that includes all but self. It is just the boids themselves, called others. Thanks y'all!